# How to replace multiple glyphs in Swift NS/UITextView with a single icon

Tags: swift, text, markdown, uitextview, nstextview

I'm struggling with this one for a while now. Its's about rendering markdown text in UI/NSTextView.

In the app "Bear" for Mac/iOS you can add a markdown link like `[This is a link](https://...com)` and it will hide the full URL and show a link symbol instead.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I know how to change colors using `NSAttributedString` and I know how to hide glyphs by overriding `NSLayoutManagerDelegate`.

There I override the `shouldGenerateGlyphs` func and change the properties of the glyphs to `.null` to hide them. Here I can also 'replace' a single glyph with something else by creating a `CGGlyph(exactly: Int)` and setting the glyph pointer to this in the same method where you can hide glyphs. But you can only replace a single glyph, not multiple.

While the above might work, it feels very hacky. I would need to hide all URL string glyphs, except the first, and turn that into a symbol somehow.

Is there any way to say something in the sense of `mergeGlyphs(in range: NSRange, to glyph: CGGlyph)` or to combine multiple glyphs to one or any other idea this could be achieved?